# Compose deep link is causing my view model data to be empty

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, deep-linking, android-viewmodel

I am working on a project that uses jetpack compose and whenever i load a composable through deep links, any data that gets loaded quickly appears then goes missing.

My deep link is pretty straight forward.

```
composable(
                DestinationScreen.Screen.route + "/{index}",
                arguments = listOf(navArgument("index") { type = NavType.StringType }),
                deepLinks = listOf(navDeepLink { uriPattern ="pattern/job/{index}" })

            ) { entry ->
                LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
                    bottomBarState.value = false
                }
                JobDetails(navController = navController, companyVm = companyViewModel,vm, jobVm,entry.arguments?.getString("index")!!  )
            }
```

Inside my composable i have a launched effect that calls a function to update the viewModel.

```
LaunchedEffect(key1 = Unit) {
            companyVm.getJob(index) {}
    }
```

all i was doing to test what was happening was changing one value in the view model

```
 var job: MutableState<JobModel> = mutableStateOf(JobModel())

  fun getJob(jobPostUid: String, onComplete: () -> Unit) {

      job.value.jobTitle = "New Title"
}
```

When the page loads normally through the app you can see the new title but when you load it through a deep link you quickly see it appear then disappear and from logs i can see that it's making the title blank.